# How to update variable values in data frame using function in R?

Tags: r, function, variables, dataframe

I create the below function to update some variables in a data frame. Instead of updating the variables it creates new variables. I am not sure why passing `P1SEG1` and `P1SEG2` to `var1` and `var2` is not working.

Data frame:

```
df <-   read.table(text="   PROD    P1SEG1  P1SEG2  
                      1 1   0   
                 2  0   0   
                 3  0   0   
                 1  1   0   
                 2  0   0   
                 3  0   0   ", header=T)
```

Function:

```
Chg.var.df <- function(data, prod, var1, var2){
  data$var1[data$PROD == prod] <- -1
  data$var2[data$PROD == prod] <- -1
  return(data)
}
```

Result:

```
Chg.var.df(df, 1, P1SEG1, P1SEG2)

  PROD P1SEG1 P1SEG2 var1 var2
1    1      1      0   -1   -1
2    2      0      0   NA   NA
3    3      0      0   NA   NA
4    1      1      0   -1   -1
5    2      0      0   NA   NA
6    3      0      0   NA   NA
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `$var1`, instead you should use it as follows: `data[data$PROD == prod, var1] <- -1`

Comment: @ProcrastinatusMaximus I get this error `Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, data$PROD == prod, var1, value = -1) : 
  duplicate subscripts for columns `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better not to use `$var1` inside a function when you want to pass a variable to `var1`. Instead you should use it as follows:

```
Chg.var.df <- function(data, prod, var1, var2){
  data[data$PROD == prod, var1] <- -1
  data[data$PROD == prod, var2] <- -1
  return(data)
}
```

Calling the function now with `Chg.var.df(df, 1, 'P1SEG1', 'P1SEG2')` will result in:

```
  PROD P1SEG1 P1SEG2
1    1     -1     -1
2    2      0      0
3    3      0      0
4    1     -1     -1
5    2      0      0
6    3      0      0
```

Answer (score 0):

The function can also be simplified by looping through the 'var' columns

```
Chg.var.df <- function(data, prod, var1, var2){
     varNew <- c(var1, var2)
     data[varNew] <- lapply(data[varNew], replace,  list = data$PROD==prod, values =-1)
     data
 }
```

By calling the function

```
Chg.var.df(df, 1, 'P1SEG1', 'P1SEG2')
#   PROD P1SEG1 P1SEG2
#1    1     -1     -1
#2    2      0      0
#3    3      0      0
#4    1     -1     -1
#5    2      0      0
#6    3      0      0
```